# Uniquely identify IOS device

Tags: iphone, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Hi I am developing iPhone application in which I want uniquely identify my device. As we know mac address for device is deprecated for IOS7 so i can not user that one. I tried with `identifierForVendor` this device property which gives me unique id for my device. But this property is application specific. That mean if I uninstall and again install my application then it will not return same id as previous one. But I want for every installation it should give me same identifier. Is there any way to do this? Need some help. Thank you.